# EF 6 - Cascade delete without fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, fluent

I have a large model using the Code-First approach using the `ForeignKey`and the `InverseProperty` attributes instead of the fluent API and i'm trying to configure cascade deletes on **certain** entities. The majority of the entities shouldn't have cascade deletes, so I removed the following conventions:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

Is there a way to configure cascade deletes with attributes on POCO classes or I should use the `DbModelBuilder.Entity...WillCascadeOnDelete(true)` on the desired entites?